# Notepad++ find string in parantheses

Tags: regex, notepad++

I try to fetch the string `modlgn_username` inside the paranthesis from the following string:

> $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("modlgn_username"))->click();

This is my regular expression:

```
\$this->webDriver->findElement\(WebDriverBy::id\("([A-z0-9]+)"\)\)->click\(\);
```

[image]

However I get **Find: Can't find text \$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("([A-Za-z0-9])"))->click();**

It works in online regex tester though:

https://regex101.com/r/6oDry3/1

Comment: It worked for me in Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will be like this

```
(?<=\(\")\w+_\w+(?=\"\))
```

it checks that from left side of the string will be (" and from right side will be ").

It mach the string you need. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

You have to add underscore in the character class or your regex and `A-z` is not a correct range, it inludes `[\]^_` and backquote:

```
\$this->webDriver->findElement\(WebDriverBy::id\("([A-Za-z0-9_]+)"\)\)->click\(\);
```

and this character class can be now reduce to `\w`:

```
\$this->webDriver->findElement\(WebDriverBy::id\("(\w+)"\)\)->click\(\);
```